# php | more effective function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a function and it works. Please check below:

```
public static function checkAccessLevel($user, $level) {

    public static function checkLevel($user, $level) {

    if ($level == "1") {
       if (!$user->usertype == 1) {
          return array(
           'error'  => 'Please login before', 'errortype' => 0
          );    
       }
    } else if ($level == "2") {
       if (!$user->usertype == 2) {
          return array(
            'error' => 'Please login before', 'errortype' => 0
          );    
       }                    
    } else if ($level == "1,2") {
       if (!$user->usertype == 1 || !$user->usertype == 2) {
           return array(
              'error'   => 'Please login before', 'errortype' => 0
           );   
       }                
    } else {
       return array(
          'error'   => 'Please login before', 'errortype' => 0
       );
    }
}
```

I'm looking the way for code optimization. Is it possible to rewrite this function?

Comment: Yes it is, but this question should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$level` is always comma separated, just break it and check:

```
public static function checkLevel($user, $level)
{
    $level = explode(',', $level);
    if(!in_array($user->usertype, $level))
        return array(
            'error' => 'Please login before',
            'errortype' => 0
        );
}
```

and better yet, throw an `Exception` or return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

First of all consider using [switch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), it should be more readable.

Then you may group your conditions, instead of:

```
 } else if ($level == "1,2") {
   if (!$user->usertype == 1 || !$user->usertype == 2) {
```

group them together:

```
(($level == "1,2") && (!$user->usertype == 1 || !$user->usertype == 2))
```

Then you may use temporary variable $result:

```
$result = array('Please login...
```

and return it at the end, instead of using return keyword in every step, it should help you in debugging.

Also I suggest to read [Martin Fowlers book about refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) which will give you many good advice.

Comment: MARTIN! MARTIN FOWLER! Not Mark lol

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function checkLevel($user, $level)
{
    if (($level == "1" && ! $user->usertype == 1) ||
        ($level == "2" && ! $user->usertype == 2) ||
        ($level == "1,2" && ! in_array($user->usertype, array(1, 2))) ||
        ! in_array($level, array("1", "2", "1,2"))) {
        return array(
            'error' => 'Please login before', 'errortype' => 0
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement instead of an if statement, like so:

```
public static function checkLevel($user, $level) {
    $result = array();
    switch($level) {
        case '1':
            if( $user->usertype == 1) {
                $result = array(
                    'error'  => 'Please login before', 'errortype' => 0
                );
            }
        break;
        // More cases for each level.
        default:
            $result = array(
                'error'  => 'Please login before', 'errortype' => 0
            );
    }

    return $result;
}
```